Redshift spectrum table query stuck on discover attribute {column name}
I have an external table in Redshift spectrum.
It works fine when I add it in a view.
But when I try to query it directly, it gets stuck on Discover attribute {column name}.
The query takes ages but doesn't return anything.

What happens if you query the underlying glue table in Athena? If it also hangs, this is an Athena issue not a redshift issue

Having this exact issue, any luck?

It turns out to be a driver issue. Upgrade to redshift-jdbc42-2.1.0.29 then problem solved.
